# Angular carousel with thumbnails and images replacement

Tags: angular, slider, carousel

Could you, please, share some examples of Angular carousels, which does this:
[image]

so,

- 1 active image
- when click to thumbnail it replace main image
- meanwhile, main image goes to thumbnail place

Comment: Here are a few examples that I found, that also include source code:

https://www.codepel.com/angularjs/angular-image-carousel-with-thumbnails/

https://codepen.io/codepel/pen/RwevbbJ

Comment: Chosen image still present in thumbnails. But aim - is to hide image, that now big.